# What should i unit test here

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Let's say i have method like that 
What should i test over here:

```
public Subscription ChangeState(TestClass testClass, DateTime currentTime)
{
    testClass.IsDisabled = true;
    testClass.IsDelete = true;

    Update(testClass);

    _logger.LogInfo($"Some Error message is going here");

    return testClass;
}
```

First that come to my mind only test IsDisabled  and IsDelete state adter test
Are there additional cases for testing?

Comment: Without more context, it's hard to say. If `ChangeState` is supposed to...change state, then you should probably check that the *state has changed*. Having said that, changing the state isn't what this function appears to do. It sets `IsDisabled` and `IsDelete` to `true`, which means if they were already true, then it didn't *change the state*. And we have no idea what `Update` is supposed to do.

Comment: is TestClass something related to your unit testing; because if so; then this isn't a path that can be taken by your live code; in which case you're testing nothing.

Comment: Ask yourself what are you testing? Then given a known set of inputs and some business logic (however simple) has the state changed of the objects your acting upon.

Comment: I'm assuming that TestClass inherits from Subscription. You pass in testClass and then return it. You would examine testClass to see how it had changed. What would you expect this method to do? - Test to see if it does that. If you know what a method is supposed to do then you have your answer to "what should I unit test"

Comment: Why not test everything?  Verify the boolean state change, verify that `Update` is called, verify that `LogInfo` is invoked, and verify that the same instance is returned.

Comment: Only the code that you require to work correctly. Testing any other code is just a waste of time

Comment: please write better questions. That code is rubbish, no need to test it... log.info("... some error here..!"). FTLOG.

Comment: @Jocke The fact that the code is poor doesn't makes the question poor. Moreover, finding test cases and having a few extra sets of eyes on the code will help uncover problems and hopefully fix them.

Comment: You are right @Alejandro - but who logs errors in level info. That is like a carpenter installing you kitchen with a rock instead of a hammer.. yes there is room for improvements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all boils down to what the method is supposed to do exactly rather than its current code, but given what you've got, I can find some dead simple tests:

- The parameter must be the same as the return value.
- Assert that both properties are set to true if sent as false.
- If the properties are both true, is it really necesary to call `Update`? This is a potential improvement that a test can discover.
- Check that `Update` is really called. Since this is another method (we don't know if private or what) you may verify its side effects.
- If no error happens, there is no need to log an error message, that's a possible bug in your implementation (although not sure if it merits a unit test).
- A clear bug is that the method doesn't check for nulls, a test will easily check that.
- Not for wirting an unit test, but the `currentTime` parameter is not used at all and should be removed.